# Hibernate Self reference

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one, self-reference

I'm trying to map with Hibernate an entity Product with self reference to other products.

The JSON sent to create a project is like this:

```
{"name":"chair", "description":"red chair",
 "parent": {"name":"table","description":"red table"}
 }
```

When I receive this json, I need to persist on DB the child product and set PARENT_PRODUCT_ID with the productId from parent attribute.

Some help, please?

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer productId;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
private List<Image> images;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
private List<Product> children;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PRODUCT_ID")
private Product parent;
```

Image.java:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Image implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer imageId;

@Column(name = "TYPE")
private String type;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
private Product product;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the oneToMany relationships, I think it should be like:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
private List<Product> children;
```

Comment: Thanks, @María. And what about the ManyToOne field for PARENT_PRODUCT_ID?

Comment: It seems to be ok.